# Lambda name mangling in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, name-mangling

I have some partial stack trace and one of the items is:

```
<lambda_b19cf42fe9374442383aa89d5c22410b>::operator()(_QWORD **, _QWORD *)
```

I know that it's a program compiled with MSVC. How are lambdas mangled? What is this `b19cf42fe9374442383aa89d5c22410b` part? Is it random, or a hash of the lambda body or something?

I'm trying to understand whether it's useful, e.g. whether I must have the exact same version of the program to match it.

Comment: That smells like some kind of cryptographic hash. 32 hex characters, 16 bytes, 128 bits. Perhaps MD5? It's likely deterministic based on the file/line number. I'm not sure the composition of the name matters here, as I don't think it's useful outside of your particular binary, as compiled. In fact, is this a real function or just a debugger label for the relevant inlined code?

Comment: FWIW, I think this is an anonymous lambda. I don't think you can reference it (or should need to).

Comment: @tadman Looks a lot like a GUID, to me.

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywhere, every lambda will have a unique name but it's a compiler implementation detail what exactly the name is

Comment: @AdrianMole Good point, a GUID is also 128 bits, though it's usually formatted differently. Microsoft does love their GUIDs!